# Checkbox Rules Script applies to a single row of checkboxes, but I can't get it to apply to multiple rows

Tags: jquery, html, loops, checkbox, this

I have made a row of checkboxes that have certain rules applied to them:
If 'Voice' or 'Mail' is checked - then 'Select' must automatically checked too.
However if 'Select' is unchecked by the user - then both 'Voice' and 'Mail' must be unchecked automatically too.
I have the fiddle for this here:
https://jsfiddle.net/monkeyroboninja/omym4efh/18/

This works fine but now I want it to apply to multiple table rows, each row able to contain their own set of values in those checkboxes. So I thought I'd need to use a loop to go through each row, change the `<td>` id attributes to class attributes (since there is multiple ones now), and also use the (this) keyword to make my jQuery apply to only the table row currently through the loop. So with this thought I made this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/monkeyroboninja/oc18um8t/11/

and here is that code in case its easier for you:

```
$(".tableRow").each(function() {

            var $select = $((this) ".select"); 
            var $voice = $((this) ".voice"); 
            var $mail = $((this) ".mail"); 

            $($(this) $voice).click(function(){                         
                if($(this).val('TRUE')){                            
                    $((this) $select).prop('checked', true);        
                }
            });

            $($(this) $mail).click(function(){                  
                if($(this).val('TRUE')){
                    $($select).prop('checked', true);
                }
            });

            $($(this) $select).click(function(){
                if($(this).val('FALSE')){
                    $($voice).prop('checked', false);
                }
            });

            $($(this) $select).click(function(){
                if($(this).val('FALSE')){
                    $($mail).prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
});
```

Aaand it didn't work! I think its the use of the (this) keyword I have wrong but what I found on the web doesn't help (or I can't understand). I do seem to have that key word everywhere!
Is anyone able to suggest where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(".tableRow").each(function() {
  var row = this;
  $(row).find(".voice").click(function(){
    if($(this).val('TRUE')){
      $(row).find('.select').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });

  $(row).find(".mail").click(function(){
    if($(this).val('TRUE')){
      $(row).find('.select').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });

  $(row).find(".select").click(function(){
    if($(this).val('FALSE')){
      $(row).find('.voice').prop('checked', false);
      $(row).find('.mail').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });                              
                
});
```

Comment: OMG that worked! Thank you, is there anything you can advise me with on where I went wrong???

Comment: You are trying to access elements by using class in current iteration/row. And for that you used "$($(this) $mail)" selector. But this is not proper way to access element using JQuery. So when you run your code, It shows SyntaxError on console.

Comment: Thanks for your input :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```js
$(".tableRow :checkbox").change(function() {

  var $this = $(this);

  // If '.select' is clicked
  if ($this.is('.select')) {
    $this
      .closest('td')
      .nextAll()
      .find('.mail, .voice')
      .prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
  }

  // if '.mail' or '.voice' is clicked
  if ($this.is('.mail, .voice')) {
    var
      $select = $this.closest('tr').find('.select'),
      $checked = $this.closest('tr').find('.mail:checked, .voice:checked');

    if ($checked.length == 2) // If both are checked
      $select.prop('checked', true);
    else // If one of them is not checked
      $select.prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: red 2px dotted;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Number Type</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Voice</th>
      <th>Mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="select" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="voice" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mail" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="select" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="voice" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mail" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>Placeholder Data</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="select" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="voice" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mail" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```